# Java android - Eclipse plugin for notify when an activity is not registered?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins, android-activity

I just wonder if exists a plugin for eclipse that notify at compile time if an activity isn't registered in the xml.

EDIT: I just want to know if specifically exists a plugin to do that, not how create an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in lint is capable of detecting such bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you use File - New - Other ... - Android Activity. It will create the class file extending `Activity` and  automatically register it in your manifest file.

Comment: I knew that, I just wondered if specifically exists a plugin that notify if the activity isn't registered in XML. I'm just curious, nothing more.

Comment: I edited the question, wasn't clear what I was asking for.